# Setting ListView row as sticky without using headers

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapterview

I have a list where I want to mark the checked/selected row as being sticky to prevent the selected item from scrolling out of the view. I have tried implementing https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders, but since it is not possible to call `addHeader` after calling `setAdapter`, I can not figure out how to do this dynamically (if even possible) based on when a list item is clicked (which is updated in `getView` of a custom adapter adapter).

I have also looked at similar libraries, but their implementation seems to be much like the one I have already tried. The author of `StickyListHeaders` is for example also the author of another similar library for `ScrollView`, but this is also not what I want, since you have to add children of each header item respectively.

So basically, I need a regular ListView where the clicked (selected) item is made sticky.